# Rally custom app completely captures whole body of the HTML page when launched

Tags: extjs, rally

We have developed a custom application in Rally(CA Agile Central) using Extjs SDK. In our final HTML page, we want to have some HTML DOM elements to be displayed alogside the UI elements created by extjs. When we try to launch this application,  UI elements created by extjs completely captures body of the HTML page and other HTML DOM elements are not visible.

e.g.

```
<body>
    <div id="ABC"></div>
    <div id="XYY">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</body>
```

We want to display UI created by extjs to be associated with div "ABC" and in div "XYZ", we want to have other elements. Currently UI elements in div XYZ are not visible once UI elements created by extjs gets loaded.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working mostly by design.  We do get this request fairly often though.  Until we can implement being able to launch apps in a specific element rather than the body the only workaround is to use an iframe in your html file and set its src attribute to your App.html file.

```
<body>
    <div id="ABC">
        <iframe src="App.html" height="800px" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div id="XYY">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your response......what we are actually trying to do is to extract data from the Rally using extjs and display this data in HTML tag on the same page. It would of great help if you could provide any example on this.